Every linear graph $X $ is normal.

Lemma 83.1. Every linear graph $X$ is Hausdorff; in fact, it is
normal.
Proof. Let $B$ and $C$ be disjoint closed subsets of $X$. Assume,
without loss of generality, that every vertex of $X$ belongs either to
$B$ or to $C$. For each $\alpha$, choose disjoint subsets $U_\alpha$
and $V_\alpha$ of $A_\alpha$, that are open in $A_\alpha$, containing
$B \cap A_\alpha$ and $C \cap A_\alpha$, respectively. Let $ U =
 \bigcup U_\alpha \ \text{and} \ V = \bigcup V_\alpha .$ Then
$U$ and $V$ contain $B$ and $C$, respectively.
We show the sets $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. If $x \in U \cap V$, then
$x \in U_\alpha \cap V_\beta$ for some $\alpha \neq \beta$. This fact
implies that $A_\alpha$ and $A_\beta$ contain the point x, which means
that x is a vertex of X. This is impossible, for if x in B, then x
lies in no set $V_\beta$, and if x in C, then x lies in no set
$U_\alpha$.

The above is from Munkres' Topology. How exactly we know that the assumption is really WLOG? what if $x$ is neither in $B$ nor in $C$?

I don't quite know what Munkres means by "linear graph," but presumably if you have a vertex $x$ neither in $B$ or in $C$ you just add it to either.

On p.502 Munkres proves

If $X$ is a linear graph, and if $C$ is a subset of $X$ that equals the union of edges and vertices of $X$, then $C$ is closed in $X$.

So let $V$ be the set of vertices that belong neither to $B$ nor to $C$. By the above statement $V$ is closed in $X$. Hence $B'  = B \cup V$ is closed in $X$ and $B' \cap C = \emptyset$.  Every vertex of $X$ belongs either to $B'$ or to $C$.
